# State was mutated as a side effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I ran into a weird problem with my code. Sorry if this is already asked, I wanted to search for the reason but I don't even know how to phrase the problem.

Essentially, I have a code similar to this:

```
class Component extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { grid: [["", "", "", ""]], base: ["", "", "", ""]};
}

csvParse = (row, column) => e => {
    const newData = Papa.parse(e.target.value).data.filter(
        x => x.length !== 1 && x[0] !== ""
    );
    //newData will result in a 2D array such as [["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"], ["9", "10", "11", "12"]]
    //newData is receiving the data from a copy and paste from a CSV file

    const { base } = this.state;
    let grid = this.state.grid

    for (let i = row; i < newData.length + row; i++) {
        for (let j = column; j < 4; j++) {
            try {
                grid[i][j] = newData[i][j];//1
            } catch (err) {
                grid.push(base);//2
                grid[i][j] = newData[i][j];//3 One of these is causing it, I don't know which
            }
        }
    }

    this.setState({grid},()=>{
        console.log(this.state.base) 
    //Actually logs ["9", "10", "11", "12"] instead of ["", "", "", ""]. Why was it mutated?
    })
};

render() {
    //The component renders a 4 X 1 grid of textareas. The number of rows will increase based on this.state.grid. Doesn't seem like its the issue.
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Grid container>
                    {this.state.grid.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                        <Fragment key={rowIndex}>
                            <Grid item xs={3}>
                                <textarea
                                    onChange={this.csvParse(rowIndex, 0)}
                                    value={row[0]}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid  item xs={3}>
                                <textarea
                                    onChange={this.csvParse(rowIndex, 1)}
                                    value={row[1]}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={3}>
                                <textarea
                                    onChange={this.csvParse(rowIndex, 2)}
                                    value={row[2]}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={3}>
                                <textarea
                                    onChange={this.csvParse(rowIndex, 3)}
                                    value={row[3]}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Fragment>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

}

Every time I ran it this.state.base would change to something else, like [""]. This code has no problem if I ran it without this.state.base

Comment: To avoid state mutations, use `Object.assign({}, mydict)` when you are copying your state to an object you plan to mutate. Object.assign will return a new object with the values in `mydict`. Otherwise JS uses pass by reference for objects, so you'll be mutating your state and causing lots of side effects. Also, it would be helpful for you to try and pare this code example down to the absolute fewest lines possible. That will help you isolate the problem. Once the problem is isolated, you'll be able to diagnose and resolve it faster. A minimal example helps you more than it helps us...

Comment: You're right, I posted too much code. I've shortened it and I added where I think the problem lies. I still don't get why base was mutated though, I did not "touch" it? Does the array.push() cause something?

Comment: these updates actually make it harder for others to reproduce your situation, as it's not a workable component. Can you please post the minimal workable component that displays your state mutation? If you can remove the CSV parsing and still demonstrate the problem it will be easy to figure out what's going on. If you can also make the content of your CSV available that will help.

Comment: Thank you so much for bearing with me. I've edit it again. Hopefully, this time it's good.

Comment: thanks for your edit but I still can't reproduce this as I don't have access to your data. Does this display the problem? https://gist.github.com/duhaime/f41b44faa4a3abfa8a2ce0348d560743 If you can minimally modify that to demonstrate the problem we can debug. Also, why don't you just build your 2d array in one fell swoop, then pass that full 2d array to your render function? That will prevent you from having to recompute the same values multiple times, and will simplify the try/catch block that you think is troubling you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I believe you want `state.base` to remain `['','','','']`. If that's the case read on. Else let me know and we can iterate.

To understand what's changing `state.base` you need to understand the difference between pass by reference and pass by value.

### Pass-by-reference vs. Pass-by-value

Essentially in pass by reference, if you create a variable `a`, then create a variable `b` equal to `a`, then change the value of a key/value in `a`, you'll also change `b`:

```
var a = {'hi': 'mom'}
var b = a;
a['hi'] = 'world';
console.log(b);
// logs {hi: 'world'}
```

In pass by value, if you create a variable `a`, then create a variable `b` equal to `a`, then change the value of `a`, you *won't* change `b`:

```
var a = true;
var b = a;
a = false;
console.log(b);
// logs true;
```

Objects `{}` and Arrays `[]` are pass by reference in JavaScript, most other primitive data types are pass by value. This is a strange but critically important facet of the language itself, and it changes the way we need to write React.

### How this applies to your case

In your case, you assign your `state.base` to `base`, then you add `base` to `grid`, then you mutate `grid`. It's only a matter of time before `state.base` gets mutated.

To avoid this, just change:

```
grid.push(base);
```

to:

```
grid.push(Object.assign([], base));
```

Object assign here will create a *new variable* with the *value* of base, and add that to grid. That prevents any changes to `grid` from modifying `state.base`.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Zymptom thanks! I'm glad we got to the bottom of it!